# Why does "Automatically detect settings" get randomly disabled?

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer-8

I assume everyone knows the automatically detect settings in the LAN settings menu.

I am wondering if anyone knows what could cause that feature to turn off randomly? eg. after a reboot mostly.

The system we use is Vista x32, wired to a network.

Thanks for the responce

Answer (score 1):

After much research I discovered this link. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/946fd3bb-bf68-4f28-aed5-d1b6194bb9f0 with the following information.

> This fixed it for me:  I turned off
>   the Dell Quickset.  Go to - Location
>   Profiler - Profile Switching - and set
>   it to manual.
>
> With Dell Quickset - Location Profiler
>   - turned on (set to automatic), I had the problem of: I had to keep checking
>   IE 8's "automatically detect settings"
>   box every time I come out of sleep
>   mode, hybernate mode, or reboot. Web
>   pages would not display, until I check
>   the  "automatically detect settings"
>   box again, every time.

I hope this helped.

-Good Luck.

Comment: thanks, i tried to do some research, but nothing comes up that looks like its a fix. I can go to the connections tab, and lan settings and then check mark that feature back in so that the internet works. but it doesn't stay there. i guess im just wondering if it is at all possible to make a registry entry that would prevent it from un-checking itself...

Comment: I would build a VB script that runs on startup that executes a Registry entry script to enable that tick box, but for the life of me I cannot remember where in the registry that value sits.